# ReactJS how to 'reset states' of a mapped array of components, on click of one of components in array

Tags: reactjs, logic, react-hooks

I will use the analogy of a 'light bulb like' on / off state throughout. A text field is considered on (or active) when it is blue, and off when it is black.

I currently have an array of text, that I map through, and the values get passed to a component.
This component manages the local state of the text, for each text on click it will flick the color blue basically (on / off)

I have a global state that I would like to be true if any item is blue. My issue is that if 'text_one' is on, and I click 'text_two', i'd effectively like 'text_one' to turn off, and 'text_two' turn on, and continue having the global state on. Essentially, only one text may be blue at a time. If you click on a text component, it will turn blue, and turn the rest off, if they are blue.

verbally, the logic (I assume) would be

```
if(global && local) then blue
if (global && !local) then black
```

If I understand react correctly, if a state changes, it should re-render all the Text Components. Using `onClick` on the component, I'm able to change the state of whatever I click, but I'm unsure how I would change the state of the rest of them to change them back to black.

My Source code is below, and can be found on codesandbox.io.

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-violet-tc3lh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState(["text_one", "text_two"]);
  const [globalActive, setGlobalActive] = useState(false);

  const TextEntry = ({ value }) => {
    const [localActive, setLocalActive] = useState(false);

    return (
      <h1
        onClick={() => {
          setLocalActive(!localActive);
          setGlobalActive(true);
        }}
        style={{
          color: localActive && globalActive ? "blue" : "black"
        }}
      >
        {value}
      </h1>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {texts.map((text, index) => {
        return <TextEntry value={text} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange logic imo. Just indentify which element you click and do a comparison.

Check it out
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-morse-pj7ro?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Is it what you wanted?